# How to get Max of sum of two columns, with associated column - SQL Live

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

```
CREATE TABLE emp
(
   empno      NUMBER (4, 0),
   ename      VARCHAR2 (10),
   job        VARCHAR2 (9),
   mgr        NUMBER (4, 0),
   hiredate   DATE,
   sal        NUMBER (7, 2),
   comm       NUMBER (7, 2),
   deptno     NUMBER (2, 0),
   CONSTRAINT pk_emp PRIMARY KEY (empno)
);
```

This is the table creation, obviously

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IjJw.png) This is the table output

Now what i need to do is find the sum of Sal + Comm for the Salesman rows, and then find the max of those sums, then display that max plus the corresponding ename

Here is my code

```
     SELECT ename, MAX (SUM (sal + comm)) max_sal
    FROM emp
   WHERE job = 'SALESMAN'
GROUP BY ename
```

I know this nowhere near correct, but I'm brand new to SQL so I'm very stuck (using SQL live btw)

Comment: This is very close to being a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as

```
 SELECT deptno,
         MAX (ename) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY sal) ename,
         MAX (sal + comm)
    FROM emp
   WHERE job = 'SALESMAN'
GROUP BY deptno
```

**DENSE_RANK** -  will aggregate over only those rows with the `MAXIMUM` first

**KEEP** will use the `MAX` function only over these results and not the complete results of your query

*Edit*

Without `dept_no`

```
SELECT MAX (ename) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY sal) ename,
       MAX (sal + comm)
  FROM scott.emp
 WHERE job = 'SALESMAN'
```

Comment: This works, but I'm not familiar with some of the code. For instance, what is this line doing: MAX (ename) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY sal) ename


and that scott.emp is confusing me as well

Comment: @GoldPonyBoy More examples are [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions)

Comment: Okay, I think I understand, but why did you use the line "FROM scott.emp"? Scott is just a random name form the table, so I'm confused

Also, my upvote doesn't change the total as I'm still too new to the site

Comment: @GoldPonyBoy `scott` is the schema name. I have removed the `scott` from the query.

Comment: This groups by `deptno` the OP's question has no requirement for this.

Comment: @MT0 I have included a SQL query without `dept_no`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to generate the Sum of two fields as subquery then you can get the MAX from your subQuery. please us the below query:

```
select oldQuery.ename,MAX(oldQuery.Max_Sal)

from (select ename, sum(sal+comm) Max_Sal

from emp

where job='SALESMAN'

group by ename) as oldQuery

group by oldQuery.ename
```

Comment: Hmm, same as the other suggestion, it is giving me an error saying the command is not properly ended I'm using Oracle Live SQL btw